# Materialize carousel onchange jquery change bg

Tags: css, materialize

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

html {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

body {
    background-color: #000000;
}

.carousel {
    height: 700px;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
            perspective: 600px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
            transform: translateY(-100px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel .carousel-item {
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: grab;
    width: 400px;
}

.carousel .carousel-item:active {
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
    cursor: grabbing;
}

.carousel .carousel-item img {
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel .carousel-item h3 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: -5px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="./img/gry1.png" alt="Dog" title="Dog" id="Dog">
    </div>
    
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="./img/img1.png" alt="Cat" title="Cat" id="Cat">
    </div>
    
        <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="./img/img1.png" alt="Wolf" title="Wolf" id="Wolf">
    </div>
    
        <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="./img/img1.png" alt="Tiger" title="Tiger" id="Tiger">
    </div>

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
```

I'd like to change background for each item in my carousel, materialize adding "active" class for selected item in carousel but I cant figure out how to change bg (for whole page), I was trying to add background image to css for each item but it didnt cover whole page bg.

I think it will be good to solve it by jquery (check which item is "active" and select background for that item, adding it to body class)

The same script available on codepen:
https://codepen.io/crianbluff/details/PMZBVJ

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from codepen

Comment: Thank you for this tip, I have edit post but on code snippet this script doesnt look good, this is the same script on codepen: https://codepen.io/crianbluff/pen/PMZBVJ

Comment: you want to change the background color of the body when onchange called? and which background color I need to call?

Comment: I want to  change background image for each carousel item, for example if active is carousel item with id dog, I need bg  with dogs, if active cat, bg with cats

Comment: ok, let me see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that.

I added the dummy data that contains `image-url` and I added `carousel-item--*` classes in HTML.

```
const setBackground = () => {
    const number = document.querySelector('.carousel-item.active').classList[1].split('--')[1];
    document.body.setAttribute('style', `background-image: url("${dummy[number]}")`);
}
```

in number variable, I am getting the `carousel-item--*` number and get the `image-url` of dummy data through index and add `background-image` through javascript

Codepen: https://codepen.io/NishargShah/pen/oNzwGwx?editors=1010